# Transferring data from int to string

Tags: php, database, logic

A user puts in their information via a scroll down menu and selects an option a couple of times. When they do this, it is saved as a INT rather then a STRING. This is because some calculations need to be run on the informaton. So essentially it looks like this:

```
   <select name="option1">
        <option value="0">Chair</option>
        <option value="10">Table</option>
        <option value="20">Counter</option>
        <option value="30">Toaster</option>
        <option value="40">Oven</option>
        <option value="50">Microwave</option>
    </select>
    <select name="option2">
        <option value="0">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
        <option value="4">Green</option>
        <option value="6">Yellow</option>
        <option value="8">Orange</option>
```

These values are added together to make a sum. So a blue(2) table(10) would have a value of 12.

My problem arises when I want users to be able to edit this data. I want to display the data they currently have, however it is now saved as a INT. How would I make it so that the information is displayed back in text format based on a the value in the database. (ie. a value of 38 would output "Orange Toaster)?

*I am doing this in PHP but I am not necassarily looking for code, just an idea on how to do this.

Comment: are you using a database?

Comment: and are you submitting this through a form? or is it using javascript as the user selects from the dropdown? Honestly, i think you need to explain your problem a bit better. Its a bit confusing what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Yes this would be through a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the options in database with the following table structure.

```
Table Name: selection_options
id(pk) option_name option_value category
1      chair       0           option1    
2      Table       10          option1    
3      Toaster     30          option1    

.
.
6      red          0          option2   
7      Orange       8          option2   
.
.
so on
```

For creating the selection box option1 execute the query as below:

```
$option1Array = "SELECT * FROM selection_options WHERE category = 'option1'" ;
```

This will give you all the options available in the category option1
Do same for the option2 now your selection boxes will be changed as below:

```
<select name="option1">
    <?php foreach($option1Array  as $option1) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option1['id']; ?>"><?php echo $option1['option_name']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
<select name="option2">
    <?php foreach($option2Array  as $option2) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $option2['option_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Now you have to save this data in the database as below:
Table Name: users_selected_options

```
id user_id option1 option2 
1     1     3      7
.
.

id: Primary key of the table
user_id: Foreign key of the user table 
option1: Foreign key of the selection_options
option2: Foreign key of the selection_options
```

No you want to show what options user has selected fire a execute join query you will get the result.

```
SELECT uso . * , so.option_name, so1.option_name, (so.option_value + so1.option_value) AS total
FROM users_selected_options AS uso
JOIN selection_options AS so ON uso.option1 = so.id
JOIN selection_options AS so1 ON uso.option2 = so1.id
WHERE user_id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The above query will give you the records as below:

```
id  user_id     option1     option2     option_name     option_name     total   
1    1             3         4          Toaster          Orange         38
```

So now you can easily iterate over the result and show the appropriate output to the user.

This solution is might be lengthy for you but it will helps in future when you want to make the 
application dynamic as.

1. Now you can easily provide the interface to add / edit  the values
   and options names.

   2.If the option names and values are being changed
   you don't have to worry about as we are getting the SUM  directly by
   the query.

   3.Now you can able to save the multiple data against the
   same user.

   4.In future if you want to provide option3 for the
   selection then you can do this change easily and you just have to
   update the query not in the entire code.

Comment: Wow awesome answer man. I will definately try something like this out.

Answer (score 1):

To start you will need to find the remainder when divided by 10.

```
if($numberX%10 == 4) { echo "Green"; }
```

Comment: If you are using non-table solution, Thomas solution is smart enough

Answer (score 1):

You need a table to save all of the options eg:

```
id info
-- ----
0  Red Chair
2  Blue Chair
...
```

But I might be better saved in 2 tables, why do you sum them up as one int?

OK since you said no need to add them up, try two tables:

```
id furniture
-- -------
10 ...

id color
-- -----
2  Blue
```

For non-table solution, you save above values into an array eg

```
$furniture = array(
    10 => '...',
    ...
);
$colors = array(
    2 => 'Blue',
    ...
);
```

It is not a good idea to make some ID value as 0

Comment: That's a good point, I guess there is no reason to add them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use math functions.
Use division that you can find remainder which would be your option2 and use subtraction (integer - remainder) = your option1